# Disable 'Add' button if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery

Disabling the button is working fine but what I'm tying to achieve is not to use ID's for the sake of maintenance because this functionality will repeat many times. What is happening now is that because of the buttons has the selectors when I select a checkbox both buttons are disable. I tried to use .siblings() to enable the other but I'm lost. This is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/XEdcd/2/)**. Any help? Thanks.

```
$('.remove-attr').siblings().attr('disabled', 'false');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to enable/disable only the button related to the checkbox :

```
$('.is-selected').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('label').next('.remove-attr').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XEdcd/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to be more careful when selecting elements, not to select each instance, but target just the specific one.

I used `$(this).parent().parent().find('.remove-attr')`, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/XEdcd/4/

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Inside of your click function you want to make sure you refer to the element that was clicked, and not all elements with the class. And then there are lots of ways to reference the related button. This might be useful: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

```
$('.remove-attr').removeAttr('disabled');

$('.is-selected').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parents('.controls').find('.remove-attr').attr('disabled', 'false');
    } else {
        $(this).parents('.controls').find('.remove-attr').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```